# Script does not continue after calling subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this python script which is running and I call a `subprocess` to run a game server. The thing is I need the script to continue while the server is running. But as soon as the sub process starts, and the server starts running, the script is paused until I shut down the game server.

How can I allow the script to continue after the server has been initialized?

```
command = f'f:&cd {server_path}&{exec_prop}'

process = subprocess.Popen(command , stdout=subprocess.PIPE , shell=True) 
    process.communicate()
```

Comment: ``.communicate()`` blocks until the subprocess is done. Why do you call it when you do not want to block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) blocks until the process terminates. Since this is not want you want, remove that line. It does not seem like you are using it to actually communicate anyway in your example.

On a side note, if you can avoid `shell=True` that is usually considered better practice. The `stdout` redirection seems unnecessary as well since you are not communicating..

Comment: Thank you, it was the .`communicate()` I just had a completely wrong understanding of what `.communicate()` does